# What is the cut-off frequency for this low pass filter?

Tags: lowpass-filter

I don't have any background in analog lowpass filters; and I am curious how can i decode this circuit. [image]

Comment: Hi! If you don't have *any* background, this would require us to explain linear network theory, opamp theory, theory of Bode diagrams… That would be a bit too broad for a single answer here, especially as we avoid doing people's homework without their help. So, please describe exactly what you've figured out so far, where exactly you're stuck, and the precise question to which an answer would get you farther.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I should have provided more context. This was a team homework some 15 years ago. I  stumbled on this file today and wanted to know what this was doing.

Comment: I had stumbled on the formula, but I messed up the 'nano' unit and hence my answer was way out of my expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for Sallen and Key filter.

Fc = 1/(2 * pi * sqrt(R1 * R2 * C1 * C2))

Or use a calculator, found one here: [Sallen-Key Low-pass Filter Design Tool](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPseikiLowkeisan.htm)

(It appears to handle "k" and "n", as a bonus)

Fc = 232 Hz, if you want to check your math.

Comment: PS—I considered this might be homework, but it would be so easy to find this info with a search anyway. But if you really want an analysis, you need to know how opamps work, etc., and need to do more digging on your own.

Comment: Thanks @nigel. 
This was a file from my old home work project

Comment: Ah, I see. Good for you, making sense out of it.

Comment: If you really want to be virtuous, re-learn all the theory behind it :)